# How to select Previous and next event from table based on date

Tags: sql

Hi i have  a table of Showings(shows), I want to be able to select the previous and next "Show" from today (getdate()))

The table structure has this; SHOW_ID, ShowNumber, Name, EventTime

```
SELECT  SHOW_ID, ShowNumber, Name, EventTime
FROM Event Where EventID = @EventID
```

Thats where i am stuck, how do i go about doing this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just clarify whether you need to do something with @EventID, or is that irrelevant to the question?

Comment: What are you trying to reach you ment by database or codebehind ?

Comment: Yes eventid is important due to the face I am doing it based on a specific event.

Comment: So do you want the events preceding and following @EventID, or do you want the events preceding and following today (getdate()). Your question seems contradictory.

Comment: Hi, eventid is a foreign key, so this table will infact have many records with the same eventid. So based on this eventid i want the previous and next from today. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, so this table is more like a "Showing" table than a "Show" table. It might be helpful to update the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Get the next showing of the event that will occur directly after the current datetime
SELECT TOP 1 SHOW_ID, ShowNumber, Name, EventTime
FROM Event WHERE EventTime > GetDate() AND EventId = @EventId
ORDER BY EventTime asc

-- Optionally, if you wanted to get the above and below results in a single SELECT, 
-- you could use a UNION here. i.e.:
-- UNION

-- Get the first event that occurred directly before the current datetime
SELECT TOP 1 SHOW_ID, ShowNumber, Name, EventTime
FROM Event WHERE EventTime < GetDate() AND EventId = @EventId
ORDER BY EventTime desc
```